# Drupal: "All languages" as default alias language in multilingual site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, multilingual

In Drupal 7 multilingual site, when a node is created with language set to something except *"Language neutral"*, its alias does not work (error 404) when site language is different from node language.

You can avoid this problem changing alias language to *"All languages"* from alias edit page (*admin/config/search/path*).

This is very annoying, because you have to do this for every new node with language support. Moreover, when *Bulk update* changes some alias, this setting is lost.

**Is there any way to get "All languages" to be set for every new alias created?**
**Is there any way to get "All languages" to be set for all alias already created?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add this code to your template.php

```
function youtheme_node_presave($node) {
         if ($node->type == 'nodetype') {
         $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
        }
}
```

this basically will save your nodes to neutral language ;)
change nodetype or add more if u need.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think a custom module should be better than hacking the theme template.

Comment: well is not hacking, drupal allow u to do that.

Comment: this is not related to theme. Theme should change only display behaviors.

Comment: Besides that, automatically changing all nodes to language neutral (i.e., throwing out the language information) is not a solution if the site really uses the node language, e.g., for views which should show just nodes in one language. Fixing the aliases problem, we should not create another one.

Comment: Making all alises neutral will not be a problem if all your aliases are unique (e.g. contain node id or language code). And views will be fine too. You still can filter views by current user language.

Comment: Themes cannot implement hooks.

Answer (score 0):

The above did work for me (from: http://bengoodyear.com/blog/drupal-7-cracking-the-multilingual-front-page-nut) but this did.

Make sure you have the modules Variable and Variable Translations switched on.
Goto admin/config/regional/i18n/variable
Select ‘Default front page’ from the list, save settings.
Goto admin/config/system/site-information, you’ll notice a block of text there saying something about some of your settings being multilingual variables and a list of links for the languages you are running which allow you to set the settings for each language.